# Two pipelines writing into single dataset in AzureDataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to point two different copy activity pipelines into single output dataset. All pipelines and dataset have frequency/availability set to `Day`. I've tried configuring pipeline1 as `"style": "StartOfInterval"` and pipeline2 as `"style": "EndOfInterval"`. But with that setup I'm getting error on publish:

> The Activity schedule does not match the schedule of the output
>   Dataset. Activity: 'MyCopyActivity'. Dataset:
>   'MyDataset'.","code":"ActivityDataSetSchedulerMismatch"

As a workaround I could create two different datasets, and point them to the same resource.

Is it possible to achieve this with single output dataset?

Comment: Are you sure the validation failure isn't because of a partial deployment of mismatching values already in Azure? Visual Studio is annoying that it validates against what has already been deployed to the target Data Factory rather than what to values are going to be from the project.

Comment: @PaulAndrew yes, I've removed all related pipelines/datasets from ADF and trying to deploy them together - still the same error

Comment: Are you looking to append one data set upon another? Or merge the columns into?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith I have similar datasets from different sources. I simply want to add them into result one after another

Answer (score 1):

If the reason is to merge multiple inputs into one output.

You could instead have a single copy activity pipeline have two separate inputs.

The data set inputs could have different availability windows and then the copy activity could combine them into one output dataset.

Comment: this doesn't work - I've created test pipeline with 2 inputs and 1 output, after execution only 1 dataset was copied

Answer (score 0):

Both pipeline and output datasets availability/scheduling properties should be same in all the cases. 
In you case, you have different "style" for Pipelines, but you are referring single output dataset which has only one style(default is Endofinterval).

For One pipeline it will match, but for other pipeline it will throw error.

To overcome this, you have to create two output datasets with same linked service. Don't forget to match the "style" of OutputDatasets with corresponding pipelines

Comment: Thanks. I've already mentioned that I can create two datasets instead. I was interested in other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to use a single output dataset in two copy activities. You need to create two datasets and point them to the same resource.